# Can I assign a click event or <A> on a whole Ember component?

Tags: javascript, css, ember.js, components, dom-events

I have an Ember component with `tagName:'li'`

The template looks like so:

```
<div> title</div>
 <div> image </div>
 <div> text </div>
```

The outcome is `<li>` blocks of the above elements, like so:

```
<li id="ember2484" class="...">
  <div>...</div>
  <div>...</div>
  <div>...</div>
</li>
```

I need to make the `<li>` clickable somehow, because I have a link url that I want to  assign to each `<li>` element.

Is that possible, to make `<li>` clickable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [Here is a small twiddle demonstrating how to do this](https://ember-twiddle.com/004b2903f215a60ee809ce2355c1ecd1?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2Ctemplates.components.my-component.hbs)
- [Documentation here](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/components/handling-events/)

---

```
import Component from '@ember/component';

export default class extends Component {
  clickCounter = 0;

  click() {
    this.set('clickCounter', this.clickCounter + 1); 
  }
}
```

// or in the old syntax

```
import Component from '@ember/component';

export default Component.extend({
  clickCounter: 0,

  click() {
    this.set('clickCounter', this.clickCounter + 1); 
  }
});
```